# Finding Youtube Chat ID without using the API

Tags: json, youtube

I hope you are all well.

Is there a way to find the YouTube Live chat ID without using code and YouTube API. I only ask this as the system we use for our broadcasts [Dizplai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2rdU.png) asks for the ChatID from the current stream to display our superchats on screen as a graphic.

Many Thanks

G.

Havent tried using the API.

Comment: Why do you want *without using code and YouTube API*?